# how to pass attributes from component's prop method to a handler?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new with react native and JavaScript so I do not know how the below method receives "attrs" from a component in a React-Native project:

```
handlerFsubmit = attrs => {
  const {
    timers
  } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    timers: timers.map(timer => {
      if (timer.id === attrs.id) {
        const {
          title,
          project
        } = attrs;
      }
      return {
        ...timer,
        title,
        project,
      };
      return timer;
    }),
  });
};
```

and in render there is:

```
timers.map((timer) => (
              <EditableTimer
                key={timer.id}
                id={timer.id}
                title={timer.title}
                project={timer.project}
                elapsed={timer.elapsed}
                isRunning={timer.isRunning}
                onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
                onRemovePress={this.handleRemovePress}
                onStartPress={this.toggleTimer}
                onStopPress={this.toggleTimer}>))
```

so I want to know how attrs recives its values and what is in attrs?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `attr` as below in your `handlerFsubmit` method :

```
timers.map((timer) => (
  <EditableTimer
    key={timer.id}
    id={timer.id}
    title={timer.title}
    project={timer.project}
    elapsed={timer.elapsed}
    isRunning={timer.isRunning}
    onFormSubmit={() => this.handlerFsubmit(timer)} // pass the timer element here
    onRemovePress={this.handleRemovePress}
    onStartPress={this.toggleTimer}
    onStopPress={this.toggleTimer}
  >
))
```

Comment: thank you dear Kishan. but I didn't understand where this variable gets its values from! is `attrs` equal to editableTimer's props? that component's prop (`onformsubmit`) did not pass any arguments but `attrs` has value! Where do these values ​​come from?

Comment: @mohsenzarrindel You can see I passed `timer` variable which is map element value. So It is the one of value of your state variable `timers`.

Comment: that is right kishan. I have not problem with your code. I want to know that way(posted in my question). I want to understand it exactly. i can do your code and it is a simple way.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to understand what you want to say. But `attrs` will contains one of value of your `timers` array.

Comment: ok. in my question: we have `onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}` without passing any argument! I think attrs is an argument but i can not see passing an argument in function call! (`onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}`). I do not know a lot about java script and can not understand this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass via bind method as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

```
  timers.map((timer) => (
      <EditableTimer
        key={timer.id}
        id={timer.id}
        title={timer.title}
        project={timer.project}
        elapsed={timer.elapsed}
        isRunning={timer.isRunning}
        onFormSubmit={this.handlerFsubmit.bind(null,timer)} 
        onRemovePress={this.handleRemovePress}
        onStartPress={this.toggleTimer}
        onStopPress={this.toggleTimer}
      >
    ))
```